# While buttons are changing color every second, how do I make the button I press stop while the other buttons continue switching colors?

Tags: java, web-development-server

I am creating a grid of 4 by 2 buttons and I want them to continuously change color. A button will stop changing colors once I press it. I have having trouble figuring how to make that one button stop changing colors if I press on it and have other buttons to continuously change color. If I press another button, that button stops changing color as well.

```
public class Hw1 extends JPanel {
static JFrame jf;
static JPanel jp;
static JButton jb;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    jf = new JFrame("Hello World!");
    int xAxis = 500;
    int yAxis = 300;
    jf.setSize(xAxis, yAxis);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jp = new JPanel();                       

    int num = 8;
    JButton[] buttonList = new JButton[num];

    int count = 0;

    // creates buttons and initially assigns random color
    for(int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            jb = new JButton("press me!");
            jb.setBounds(i * (xAxis/2), j * (yAxis/4), xAxis/2, yAxis/4);
            jb.setVisible(true);
            jb.setOpaque(true);
            int primeR = (int)(Math.random() * 255+ 0);
            int primeG = (int)(Math.random() * 255 + 0);
            int primeB = (int)(Math.random() * 255 + 0);
            Color random = new Color(primeR, primeG, primeB);
            jb.setBackground(random);
            // adds action listener to each button aka checks if button is pressed 
            jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                // action if button is pressed
                //if pressed change stop changing colors 
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    JButton theButton = (JButton)ae.getSource();
                    theButton.setBackground(random);  
                }
            });

            buttonList[count] = jb;
            count++;
            jp.add(jb);

        }
    }
    jf.add(jp);
    jf.setVisible(true);


    for (int k = 0; k < buttonList.length; k++) {
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                while(true){
                    try {
                            sleep(1000);
                        } 
                    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++) {
                        int primeR = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
                        int primeG = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
                        int primeB = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
                        Color random = new Color(primeR, primeG, primeB);
                        buttonList[i].setBackground(random);
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();

    }


}
```

}

Comment: What if, in the main method you keep a boolean array `hasBeenPressed[buttonNumber]`, and, inside of the nested loop (j), a if-statement that checks the values and only let the button update it's color if the corresponding value in the boolean array is true?

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep state of button.
If you have grid of 4 button, make an array of it's state `buttonState = new Boolean[2][2]`

when button on position x,y is pressed, set value of [x][y] to true. check `buttonState`  before changing color of button.

OR

Overwrite JButton and add bolean field `pressed` to it, and set it to true in `onClick`, and based on that value change or not change color

Comment: thanks, i used .isEnabled boolean instead, and .setEnabled to set the value when the button is pressed.